# cmake error catkin package

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorials in order and have been asked to configure the catkin environment at stage 5 of this web page: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Common_step_for_msg_and_srv)

The error I am receiving is as follows (bold below):

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   roscpp
   rospy
   std_msgs
   message_generation
)



## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
  FILES
  Num.msg
)

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   AddTwoInts.srv
 )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)


catkin_package(
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)



include_directories(

  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Everything above is copied exactly from the CMakeLists.txt file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271723/cmake-error-catkin-package/) by [danny5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/31904/danny5555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-28**:\

> ```
> catkin_package() called with unused arguments
> ```

this is the actual error, the rest is normal output.

Please *edit* your question and include the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt`. Please **remove all comments** from it, we don't need those.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-29**:
The sourcing is fine. You need to source both, ROS's setup script in `/opt/ros/kinetic` directory and your catkin ws as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-30**:
No, that is actually not necessary. By default, `source`-ing one `setup.bash` after another will actually make the second `setup.bash` *overwrite* whatever the first `setup.bash` configured. So sourcing your workspace after `/opt/ros/$distro` does not work the way you imply.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-30**:
Don't you have to source all your own created packages for ROS to be able to find them?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-30**:
no, you have to `source` your own *workspaces*. As you cannot compile your workspace without `source`-ing `/opt/ros/$distro`, and doing that will result in `/opt/ros/$distro` being *extended* by your workspace, `source`-ing your workspace will automatically also `source /opt/ros/$distro` (in a way).

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-09-30**:
Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for clarification.

**Comment by [danny5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/31904/danny5555/) on 2017-10-06**:
Thanks for the directory sourcing comments. I know everything is okay there now!

I have added the CMakeLists.txt file and have deleted the other comments. However the action files comment is still in there. I'm not sure if this is the reason why there were unused arguments in the original problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-06**:\

> ```
> catkin_package(
> ```

```
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)
```

Seeing as the error is actually in this bit, please copy-paste those lines from your `CMakeLists.txt` into your question *verbatim*. Don't leave anything out.

**Comment by [danny5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/31904/danny5555/) on 2017-10-06**:
I have copied exactly what is in my CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> catkin_package(
> ```

```
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)
```

The `...` are the problem here. That is not valid CMake.

Please remove them and try again, and please tell us why you thought you had to add those.

And for future reference, see also the [Catkin Howto documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html).

---

Edit: ah, I think I know why you did that. Section 2.1 (*Creating a msg*) actually has this:

> Also make sure you export the message runtime dependency.
>
> ```
> catkin_package(
> ```

```
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)
```

That `...` is called an *ellipsis* and is typically used in writing to indicate that some text has been left out, but that 'something' should be there. This is normally done to draw attention to only certain parts of the text, while still conveying the fact that those parts are still that, *parts*, and that there is actually more there.

See also [wikipedia/ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis).

So in this case, you are supposed to *add* the `CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime` bit (if it isn't already there), while keeping whatever lines were already in the `catkin_package(..)` statement before.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1